# PHP Custom Error Handler Class logging/displaying duplicate errors

Tags: php, custom-error-handling

This is the first time that I have used custom error handling and have decided to go the route of creating a class. Currently it works, but with side effects.

current ini values:

```
error_log = errors.log
display_errors = 0
log_errors = 1
```

PHP line of code:

```
include('fakefile.php');
```

Error generated:

```
WARNING:  
    Code: 2
    Message: include(fakefile.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
    File: F:\laragon\www\projects\JLDesignNetwork\index.php
    Line: 71

WARNING:  
    Code: 2
    Message: include(): Failed opening 'fakefile.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;F:/laragon/etc/php/pear')
    File: F:\laragon\www\projects\JLDesignNetwork\index.php
    Line: 71
```

error_handler.class.php

```
class ErrorHandler
{
    private $mailable = array(E_ERROR, E_USER_ERROR, E_USER_WARNING, E_WARNING);
    private $friendlyMsg = "We have encountered an unexpected error. The administrator has been notified. Please check back later.";
    private $logfile = null;
    private $techMail = null;
    private $mute = false;
    private $debug = false;
    private $details = null;
        
    function __construct($logfile=null, $techMail=null, $mute=false, $debug=false)
    {
        $this->logfile = $logfile; // should check to see if file exists
        $this->techMail = $techMail;  // should verify email is in valid format
        $this->mute = $mute;
        $this->debug = $debug;
        
        ini_set('error_log', $logfile);
        set_error_handler(array($this, 'customHandler'));
    }
    
    public function customHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfi, $errli)
    {
        $this->logstr = json_encode([
            "datetime" => date(DATE_RFC2822),
            "error" => [
                "code" => $errno,
                "file" => $errfi,
                "line" => $errli,
                "msg" => $errstr
            ]
        ],
        JSON_FORCE_OBJECT & JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            
        $this->details = array($errno, $errstr, $errfi, $errli);
        $this->response();
        
        if(in_array($errno, $this->mailable)): $this->sendMail(); endif;
    }
        
    private function response() 
    {
        error_log(
            $this->logstr. PHP_EOL,
            3,
            $this->logfile
        );
            
        $display = sprintf(
            "\tCode: %d\n\tMessage: %s\n\tFile: %s\n\tLine: %d</pre>", 
            $this->details[0],
            $this->details[1],
            $this->details[2],
            $this->details[3]
        );
            
        // display an error message; shutdown if needed
        switch($this->details[0]):
            case E_USER_ERROR:
            case E_ERROR:
                $str = $this->debug ? "<pre><b>FATAL:</b> <br>" . $display : $this->friendlyMsg;
                break;
            case E_USER_WARNING:
            case E_WARNING:
                $str = $this->debug ? "<pre><b>WARNING:</b>  <br>" . $display  : $this->friendlyMsg;
                break;
            case E_USER_NOTICE:
            case E_NOTICE:
                $str = $this->debug ? "<pre><b>NOTICE:</b>  <br>" . $display  : $this->friendlyMsg;
                break;
            default :
                // do nothing
                break;
        endswitch;
            
        if(!$this->mute): echo $str; endif;
    }
        
    private function sendMail()
    {
        $html = sprintf("<h3>An error has occurred!</h3><hr>The following error was recently logged: <pre>%s</pre>", print_r(json_decode($this->logstr),true));
        /*error_log(
            $html,
            1,
            $this->techMail,
            'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'
        );*/
    }
}
    
$eh = new ErrorHandler('errors.log', 'someone@somewhere.net', false, true);
```

My question is this -> Why is the include error both logged and displayed (on screen) twice?

Please keep in mind that this is not live and is still a work in progress.

Comment: Well, I would say that you send it twice with `error_log` & `echo` in the response method. Have you tried to enable your `mute` attribute to see if it's only displayed once?

Comment: I don’t believe that is the issue because a division by zero is only displayed once. Whereas the include error shows twice.